# EF Core: Many-to-Many relationship where only one table has the foreign id

Tags: entity-framework-core

First off, I'm probably going to get some of the terminology wrong.

Second, I don't have control over the data structure; I can make suggestions, but I cannot make changes.

I have two tables: `Customer` and `Account`:

- `Customer`s can be on multiple `Account`s
- `Account`s can have multiple `Customer`s

The tables look like this:

```
CREATE TABLE "Customer" 
(
    "cstno" NVARCHAR(255) NULL,
    "acctno" NVARCHAR(255) NULL
    -- other columns
);

CREATE TABLE "Account"  
(
    "acctno" NVARCHAR(255) NULL
    -- other columns
);
```

There are no foreign key constraints (there aren't even primary key constraints!).

What I'd like to do is this:

```
public class Customer 
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Account> Accounts { get; set; } = new List<Account>();
    // etc.
}

public class Account  
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Customer> Customers { get; set; } = new List<Customer>();
    // etc.
}
```

Also, the current pattern of my `DbContext` uses `IEntityTypeConfiguration` classes, so those would look like this without the many-to-many relationship set up.

```
public class CustomerTypeConfiguration : IEntityTypeConfiguration<Customer> 
{
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<Customer> builder) 
    {
        builder.ToTable("Customer");
        builder.Property(e => e.Id).HasColumnName("cstno");
        // etc.
    }
}

public class AccountTypeConfiguration : IEntityTypeConfiguration<Account> 
{
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<Account> builder) 
    {
        builder.ToTable("Account");
        builder.Property(e => e.Id).HasColumnName("acctno");
        //etc.
    }
}
```

How can I set up the many-to-many relationship between these two entities when only one table has the id from the other table, and there are no constraints whatsoever?

Comment: (almost) **EVERY** table in a relational database ought to have a proper primary key - without it, EF Core won't be happy at all, and establishing foreign key relationships will be somewhere between hard and impossible. Fix that as the first step - then let's see ....